# Is there any way to stop the batch jobs (.cmd and .bat) rather that force taskkill using batch script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

Is pressing ctrl + c while running batch job and taskkill /f /im cmd.exe same?

Actually I want to close three batch jobs ((2)cmd's and (1)bat files) through batch script. I found there is no command for stop like start. I don't want to kill parent image name (cmd.exe) as well using force taskkill. Manually I used to press ctrl + c to terminate the job. I don't want to use this any more. Is there any way to kill/stop the running job rather that force taskkill?
Thanks for your time!

Comment: You will have to provide us some more information about your bat files. Afaik there is no other way. The difference betreen CTRL+C and killing a task concerning CMD is that the first option stops a task asking you to confirm you want to terminate and the second one just kills the task. There is no big differenc. The only othe option I can think of is a kind of flag. Your bat scripts wiould check this flag in a loop and terminate if the flag is set.

Comment: Bat files will turn on services and weblogic (not shown in services.msc). After pressing Ctrl + c, I would press Y to terminate the task. I don't want to use this anymore but I want to automate this to terminate this entire cmd files (3).

Comment: The only way I can see is to use taskkill or a flag, as I've already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This has to be set from one of the console programs. You'll need to write a program to do it.

**GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent**

Sends a specified signal to a console process group that shares the console associated with the calling process.

```
BOOL WINAPI GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(
  DWORD dwCtrlEvent,
  DWORD dwProcessGroupId
);
```

**Parameters**

```
dwCtrlEvent
```

[in] Type of signal to generate. This parameter can be one of the following values.

Value Meaning

**CTRL_C_EVENT**

0 Generates a CTRL+C signal. This signal cannot be generated for process groups. If dwProcessGroupId is nonzero, this function will succeed, but the CTRL+C signal will not be received by processes within the specified process group.

**CTRL_BREAK_EVENT**

1 Generates a CTRL+BREAK signal.